# pip install require tls/ssl

Tags: python, linux, pip, vps

I have got a problem with install python on my OVH vps server kubuntu 14.04 desktop. What i need to do ?

```
 :~/Desktop# python get-pip.py
    pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
    Collecting pip
      Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
      Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
    No matching distribution found for pip
```

Comment: what version of `python` do you have?

Comment: pip install ssl

Comment: Sounds like you installed Python by running make, right ? In that case I'd recommend installing libssl-dev and rebuilding+reinstalling Python

Answer (score 3):

Calling more attention to @Arduino_Sentinel 's comment

> Sounds like you installed Python by running make, right ? In that case I'd recommend installing libssl-dev and rebuilding+reinstalling Python

On a fresh debian installation, I had installed Python 3.6 via

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.3/Python-3.6.3.tgz
tar xvf Python-3.6.3.tgz
cd Python-3.6.3
./configure
make
make altinstall
```

creating a virtualenv with `virtualenv -p python3.6 env` and subsequently trying to install anything with `env/bin/pip` would produce the errors from the question.

The comment quoted above solved the issue on my server.

> The main problem is you compiling python before install the libssl.

Answer (score 1):

You should trying installing form your packages repos

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Comment: What if updating pip through the package manager is not an option?