# pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available

Tags: python, pip

I am using Python 3.6. When I try to install "modules" using `pip3`, I face this issue:

```bash
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available
```

Comment: operating system?

Comment: if it is os x: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280956/ignoring-ensurepip-failure-pip-7-1-2-requires-ssl-tls-python-3-x-os-x#35282183

Comment: Operating system is oracle linux 7.x

Comment: Do you installed pip from package manager? If you installed compiling, first install `libssl-dev` or install ssl from pip `pip install ssl` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098252/pip-install-require-tsl-ssl

Comment: @ZiTAL ``pip`` doesn't work becuse of ``ssl`` and you ask to install ``ssl``, with pip :)

Comment: Any solution not requiring to recompile or reinstall python?

Comment: solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57586800/2083877

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building Python 3.7.1 - SSL module failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53543477/building-python-3-7-1-ssl-module-failed)

Comment: OSX `brew reinstall python` worked for me

Comment: Any idea how do we fix this issue in case of Amazon Linux, which supports only ```yum``` commands for installation...?

Answer (score 366):

For Windows 10
if you want use pip in normal cmd, not only in Anaconda prompt. you need add 3 environment paths.
like the followings:

```
D:\Anaconda3 
D:\Anaconda3\Scripts
D:\Anaconda3\Library\bin
```

most people only add D:\Anaconda3\Scripts

Comment: Thanks, I've added  D:\Anaconda3\Library\bin and it works, by the way the libssl-1_1-x64.dll is in that folder. (win10x64, python 3.7)

Comment: when you add those three in your path close the cmd go back to it and try again it should work.

Comment: What do yo u mean by environment paths? do you mean the PATH environemnt variable? plus I do not have those folders in my D drive, are they supposed to be created when I install Anaconda?

Comment: An also for windows 8.1

Comment: This does NOT work if one is not using Anaconda. I have experienced this issue with OSGeo4W64 and QGIS 3.10.2 installations.  Adding what I gather are the correct paths to the PATH variable does not fix the issue (ex: `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37\Scripts`).

Comment: Note the path to Anaconda on your machine may be different, e.g. `C:\Users\myUsername\Anaconda3`

Comment: Setting env paths:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows

Comment: Thanks so much! Solved on Win10 after a frustrating search.

Comment: @CNIDog I fixed this by installing the 32 bit version of OSGeo4W

Comment: What if you don't have a D:/ disk?

Comment: Worked for me using miniconda on Win 10

Comment: Anaconda is a default base environment. If one is trying to install modules in a virtual environment, modify `activate` or `activate.bat` (on Windows) and include the 3 directories when resetting %PATH%.

Comment: No! PATH appears ok but it's not the right answer. After adding your PATH and pip works then, it installed packages to an uncertain place!! Keep on using conda prompt is the correct answer.

Comment: I was using Miniconda3 installed for the current user on Windows 10, and these directories are already on the PATH, so this didn't work.  What worked for me was the answer from @datchung to copy the libcrypto and libsll DLLs to the DLLs folder.

Answer (score 254):

### MAC OS

I had the same problem on Mac OS(Mojave) and solved the problem as mentioned on this link - [Openssl issue](https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI/issues/86).

1. **If you do not have Homebrew or don't know what is Homebrew:**

```sh
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

2. **Or if you already have Homebrew installed:**

```sh
brew update && brew upgrade
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl; brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
```

Update:
Keep in mind, that I had to use `--ignore-dependencies` flag, because  other packages installed that depend on OpenSSL.

Additional if the problem is caused after using **pyenv**, you can fix it by using:

```
brew reinstall python
```

Comment: After  installing another `Python`  version , pip was broken. this solution helped me repair.

Comment: why is https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb also added as a dependency? :) I think it should be removed as it is totally unrelated and potentially unsecure

Comment: I understand that it could be a security risk but all over users have asked to use the package over the official package link - https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI/issues/635

Comment: That solved my problem! Don't forget to `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: This solved my problem! Wondering what's that openssl package is though?

Comment: @Vaulstein I am actually asking about the openssl package in the github :p. More worried about that. Is this issue quite recent? I never had this issue up till now. Seems like openssl package in brew is broken somehow.

Still, much thanks for this solution!

Comment: I think it is a combination of things that is breaking openssl. Something to do with multiple python versions and openssl. Else it works fine. For me it was more specifically pyenv that broke things. It installs such a lot of shitload.

Comment: @Vaulstein Now that you mention it. I think I installed some packages using brew as well before this broke. It was `gpg`.

Comment: After upgrading from `Mojave` to `Catalina`, I hit this. I only needed `brew update && brew upgrade` for it to work again. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: {code}brew update && brew upgrade{code} fixed it for me, though it failed to install python3 in /usr/loca/lib/bin . This was fixed with {code}export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin:$PATH"; export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/lib"{code}

Comment: Additionally, if you are in a virtualenv, deactivate the virtualenv, create a new venv and then proceed.

Comment: Hi! I am using asdf on Mac. Had Python version 3.6.8. When I installed, using asdf, python 3.8.2, issue was gone.

Comment: No criticizing your answer (more the situation in general), but needing to use `brew upgrade` (which will upgrade all my dependencies globally, which in turn can make other things break) is really messed up to solve a problem I'm having for a particular project.

Comment: I am on Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6. Everything was working fine until last night and this morning started receiving the error. This solution worked for me ! Thanks much !

Comment: For me simply `brew update && brew upgrade` fixed the issue on Mac OS X.

Comment: great! it finally worked after "brew reinstall python". Thanks !

Comment: `brew update && brew upgrade` works indeed; but if you're like me, don't forget to `source ~/.bashshrc` or `source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: For me `brew reinstall python` resulted in `python@3.8 3.7.3 is already installed`
So I upgraded as suggested: `brew upgrade python@3.8` It worked

Comment: This had been driving me crazy, because I usually just write code in Sublime or some other text editor. I chose to finally give PyCharm a try and this was killing me! The 

`brew reinstall python`

Comment: DONT USE THE SECOND SCRIPT! IT INCLUDES brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb WHICH IS NOT JUSTIFIED AND SUSPECIOUS!!

Answer (score 117):

For Debian users, the following may be of use:

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev libncurses5-dev libsqlite3-dev libreadline-dev libtk8.6 libgdm-dev libdb4o-cil-dev libpcap-dev
```

Then cd to the folder with the Python 3.X library source code and run:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: @MehmetKurtipek, I edited the answer to clarify a step. If this still does not help, please clarify your problem

Comment: turned out that Python3.7 has nice problems along with Ubuntu 14.04 and older. The minimum required SSL package for Python3.7 is not compatible with old ubuntus. So thanks for editing :)

Comment: @MehmetKurtipek My server is 1404. So what is the latest version of python that don't have this problem. I have python 3.7.4 have the same problem...

Comment: @MehmetKurtipek Have you solve the problem without upgrading the system? I am also working on 14.04

Comment: using mint19 and python 3.8, this fixed my problem

Comment: Where is the folder with the python library source code? I tried the following but could not run ./configure in any of them.
/usr/local/lib/python39.zip
/usr/local/lib/python3.9
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages

Comment: Thx, it's really helpful!

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. I gave you an upvote, but I am wondering why you put each install on a separate line. The separate lines make reading clear, but copying and pasting is more arduous. Have you considered making it a one-liner?

Comment: This is great thank you!  May I recommend adding `libffi<X>` to this list.  After running the `sudo apt install ...`, I still needed to install `libffi7`.

Comment: I only needed to install `libssl-dev` (not sure if the other packages were already installed or not), but otherwise this worked for me.

Comment: This one works for me!

Comment: this one works for me. my environment: python 3.11, ubuntu 20.04 :)

Comment: I ran into the same problem, trying to install Python 3.11.1 on Debian-based Raspberry Pi OS. The ssl module in Python >= 3.10 requires OpenSSL 1.1.1 or higher (https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#module-ssl). The PI was still running on Stretch (with OpenSSL 1.1.0).  After updating OpenSSL I had to run `./configure` with the flags  `--with-openssl=/path/to/openssl --with-openssl-rpath=auto`.

Comment: All the answers failed. I debugged using `python` and then `import ssl` and saw that it failed loading `_ssl`. Then I transferred `/usr/local/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-311-aarch64-linux-gnu.so` from a server that already had a working Python3.11, and it worked like a charm. PS: I used `find / -type f -name '_ssl*' 2>/dev/null` to look for the right file...

Answer (score 91):

I'm using Windows 10 and installed Miniconda 3 with Python 3.7.

I solved this error by following this https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8273

Specifically, I copied the following files from `C:\Users\<user>\Miniconda3\Library\bin` to `C:\Users\<user>\Miniconda3\DLLs`:

- libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
- libcrypto-1_1-x64.pdb
- libssl-1_1-x64.dll
- libssl-1_1-x64.pdb

If you work in an environment, it will be from `C:\Users\<user>\Miniconda3\envs\<name>\Library\bin` to `C:\Users\<user>\Miniconda3\envs\<name>\DLLs`:

Comment: This works; thanks ... Windows 10 (Anaconda) on two machines.

Comment: This worked for me too. I have Anaconda installed not Miniconda but I was not using it or so I thought. I set up a new project from scratch in vscode with a .venv and was unable to install packages until I did this.

Comment: AWESOME!!! It worked for me!!! thank you so much, bro ;)

Comment: Thanks, its work for me on SQL Server Enviromment and Windows 11.
Use the same login copping files from C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\Library\bin to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\DLLs

Comment: This worked for me, same as @Abelini except on Win10. SQL Server Machine Learning Tools (sp_execute_external_script) doesn't provide any other way to install packages except pip. Sounds like there will be a non-pip tool in SQL Server 2022.

Comment: This worked also for Anaconda! Thank you

Comment: Can confirm this worked for me, although I only copied the *.dll files

Comment: Just to add to this. In case you're using a conda env, then the path are C:\Users\MyUser\Miniconda3\envs\<NAME_OF_YOUR_ENV>\Library\bin to C:\Users\MyUser\Miniconda3\envs\<NAME_OF_YOUR_ENV>\DLLs

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked for me on Windows 11.

Comment: Works in Windows 7 too

Comment: This did not work but @CoMartel comment did work. That comment is essential

Answer (score 61):

For centos 7:

Install openssl:

```
sudo yum install openssl-devel
```

now goto python directory were we extracted the python tar,

run below commands

```
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

This will fix the problem in centos...

Comment: Not working for Python 3.8. Any other possible solution?

Comment: @yuv try reinstalling python 3 it's been a while I used unix

Comment: Worked for me for python 3.8.1 !

Comment: I see "Package 1:openssl-devel-1.0.2k-25.el7_9.x86_64 already installed and latest version", so this was available when I built python 3.10.4

Comment: This worked for me for Python3.8

Comment: Not working for `Python3.10.6` on `RedHat 7.9`.

Comment: @hafiz031, did you figure it out?

Comment: @AndreMarin my finding is: when your operating system's version is too old than the `python`'s version you are trying to install, then this problem occurs. I tried installing `Python3.10.6` in `RedHat 9` which worked.

Comment: Not working for Python3.10.6 on Centos 7

Comment: Any fixes available now? i dont have the option to change my centos7 into centos stream altogether! @Mr.Pancho

Comment: This indeed worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: This answer may not fix our issue, but the direction is right. **this issue is caused by lack of dependencies during make and install Python source code.** Solution: `yum install yum-utils`,  `yum-builddep python3`. then `./configure`, `make && make install` is the right way to install Python from source code.

Comment: Also see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75114549/9913319.

Answer (score 37):

For future Oracle Linux users trying to solve this, below is what worked for me.
First install missing libs:

```
yum install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel 
readline-devel tk-devel gdbm-devel db4-devel libpcap-devel xz-devel
```

Then cd to your Python3.X library and run:

```
make
make install
```

Comment: This answer has addressed the problem well on my CentOS 7.

Comment: What are these libraries? Why are they required?

Comment: Doing a secure connection over the internet requires this - for instance when you  run 'pip install'

Comment: @MohitMotwani - fuhgeddaboudit... https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fuhgeddaboudit

Comment: Indeed, not everybody wants dgdbm or tk-devel libraries. Especially for servers.

Comment: Solved issue for pip3 upon python 3.6.12 installation in image amazonlinux:2.0.20220912.1

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75114549/9913319 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70840635/9913319

Answer (score 32):

## macOS, pyenv

In case of your python being an `pyenv` installed one, where pyenv is installed with homebrew on macOS, there might me a newer version available which fixes this:

```sh
$ brew update && brew upgrade pyenv
```

Then reinstalling the python version:

```sh
$ pyenv install 3.7.2
pyenv: /Users/luckydonald/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2 already exists
continue with installation? (y/N)
```

Note, it is a bit dirty to overwrite the existing python install like that, but in my case it did work out. Probably cleaner to delete it and then recreate it properly.

Comment: saved the day !

Comment: Thank youuuuu. This kind of convoluted crap I just spent 3 hours on is why I hate Python.

Comment: Try upgrading npm packages for fun, and you'll love that python does so many things right.

Comment: @luckydonald `openssl@1` is deprecated. I removed it with `brew`. I didn't realize so many brew packages were linked to it. I corrected those by removing and reinstalling. I didn't realize some python packages were also linked to that same brew installed `openssl@1` package. Your advice solved my issue.

Answer (score 20):

Worked for me.

```sh
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Use this to enable ssl for pip.
Let me know if someone encounters issues.

Comment: Didn't help in CentOS 7 for Python 3,11

Answer (score 19):

For Windows 10,windows 7
If pip install is not working on CMD prompt, run it using Anaconda prompt - it works.

https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1139

Comment: I know the right answer, if you want use pip in normal cmd, not Anaconda prompt
you need add 3 environment paths:
like these:
D:\Anaconda3; 
D:\Anaconda3\Scripts; 
D:\Anaconda3\Library\bin 

now only Scripts !

Comment: @无名小路 No! PATH appears ok but it's not the right answer. After adding your PATH and pip works then, it installed packages to an uncertain place!!  Keep on using conda prompt is the correct answer.

Comment: Did not work for me ...

Answer (score 11):

Encountered this issue while installing python 3.8 from source on ubuntu. The steps needed to install it successfully alongside the default python 3.7 are summarised below :

```
sudo apt -y install libssl-dev zlib1g-dev build-essential

wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.0/Python-3.8.0.tgz
tar -xf Python-3.8.0.tgz
cd Python-3.8.0/

./configure --enable-optimizations
make
sudo make altinstall
```

The install instruction for *zlib1g-dev* and *build-essential* is redundant, as ubuntu desktop already has these, but was necessary for some of Amazon's EC2 instances. python 3.8.0 is the current release just now, but should be replaced with the latest available.

These instructions are best for keeping python 3.7 as the default for python3, and running python 3.8 in a virtual environment.

Comment: Aside from an error with the `make` step (I'm not sure that's even needed), this answer solved my problem of how to get pip for Python 3.11 working on a Raspberry Pi. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Similar to the above [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61429593/5335565) reinstall the python version with pyenv.

Somehow, I upgraded my `openssl` which broke the pyenv version python.

```sh
pyenv install 3.6.8
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
...
```

The first line says it relies on the homebrew openssl.

Comment: Same here, my python3.10 just became 3.6 .

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I reinstalled Python. It solved the problem.

```
brew reinstall python
```

Answer (score 6):

For OpenSUSE in the same manner, but a few changes of listed above packages:

```
zypper install zlib-devel libopenssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite3-devel readline-devel tk-devel gdbm-devel libpcap-devel xz-devel
```

Then `cd` to Python sources dir and

```
make
make install
```

or

```
make
make altinstall
```

And perhaps

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/ /usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
```

should be executed for OpenSUSE users. See [Python 3.7 install not working on openSUSE Leap 42.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201459/python-3-7-install-not-working-on-opensuse-leap-42-3)

Answer (score 5):

Just try installing through Anaconda prompt

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue with Visual Studio Code installing pylint from the VS Code prompt.
I was able to overcome the issue by opening the Anaconda installation directory and running

```
pip install pylint
```

Then VS Code was happy, but that did not fix the issue as running

```
& C:/Users/happy/Anaconda3/python.exe -m pip install -U pylint
```

pretty much gave the same error so it seems that VS Code is unable to access the python modules.

Note that VS Code picks up the first python env it see when installed, the bottom left of the screen indicates which env is being used. Clicking on that area allows to set the environment. So even if you ran the pip install for an environment VS Code could be looking at a different one.

Best approach was to make sure that VS code had the correct python environment selected and that same environment is in the system PATH (under System Properties --> Advanced --> Environmental Variables)

Under the Path Variable, Edit and browse to the specific Anaconda directory that you want VSCode to use and add to PATH, I needed to Add the following:

```
C:\Users\happy\Anaconda3\
C:\Users\happy\Anaconda3\Scripts\
C:\Users\happy\Anaconda3\Library\bin\
C:\Users\happy\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin\
```

Your Anaconda installation directory may differ.
One note is that Windows does not have the PATH variable take effect until you restart the terminal. In this case close and re-op VS code. If using a Terminal or PS Shell then close and reopen and check Path to make sure it is included.

Answer (score 5):

The problem probably comes from your installed openssl package version. That was the case for me and I fixed this issue just upgrading it. I'm on Mac OS, using brew :

```
brew upgrade openssl
```

If you installed python with brew, this should directly fix the issue with it, as python is dependent on openssl

Answer (score 5):

Newest Python 3.8.4 or higher should able to support https protocol out of box. If you still have old python installation on your pc - either download & install python3 manually, or using Chocolatey:

If you don't have Chocolatey, install it - from here: https://chocolatey.org/docs/installation

You can just copy paste one command line liner and execute it from command prompt with elevated priviledges.

```
choco install python3
```

if you don't have python3 installed, or you you have it installed - then:

```
choco upgrade python3
```

Notice also that you can use also anaconda distribution, as it has built-in python with https support, but this rather ancient instructions, no need to follow them anymore.

Install anaconda, using command line:

```
choco install anaconda3
```

Set environment variables:

```
set PATH=C:\tools\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\tools\Anaconda3;C:\tools\Anaconda3\Library\bin;%PATH%
```

and then run command which failed. In my case it was:

```
pip install conan
```

Anaconda uses separate python installation, and pip is also anaconda specific.

Answer (score 5):

Worked for me.

```sh
pkg install openssl
```

Use this to enable ssl.

Comment: Worked for me too (tried to install Django via Termux). Android 8. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If someone is using Arch Linux OS, I solved the TLS/SSL problem by running this:

```
sudo pacman -S openssl
```

Then I could use pip to install the package I needed:

```
pip install openpyxl
```

Comment: Update for 2022: the `openssl` package is 3.0 and python seems to be looking for the 1.x module. I was able to fix with:

`sudo pacman -S openssl-1.1`

Answer (score 4):

Go to Anaconda prompt and type (if you have python 3.x installed on your engine) :

```
py -m pip install pymysql
```

i was having the same issue and this solved my problem. later after doing this you can import pymysql in power shell or any other prompt.

Answer (score 3):

As Tokci said, it also works for Windows 7.

"Go with the mouse to the Windows Icon (lower left) and start typing "Anaconda". There should show up some matching entries. Select "Anaconda Prompt". A new command window, named "Anaconda Prompt" will open."

Then pip works.

The following also helped to import xgboost:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05djBSOs1FA

Comment: Looking for the linux equivalent ... but anyway, why would this work and using pip from the command line won't? this only makes sense if you already rebuilt anaconda's python with SSL beforehand at some point.

Comment: I have no idea why but what you say sounds reasonable

Answer (score 2):

The issue is due to OpenSSL package is missing on your PC.

If  `pip install openpyxl` also gives error.

you can fix this by installing OpenSSL(Win64 OpenSSL v1.1.1g) from below site :

```
slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html
```

Restart the IDE you are using, for changes to be in effect.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 10 SQL Server 19 the solution is known.

Copy the following files:

- libssl-1_1-x64.dll
- libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll

from the folder

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\Library\bin

to the folder

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\DLLs

Then open a new DOS command shell prompt.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/troubleshooting/known-issues-for-sql-server-machine-learning-services?view=sql-server-ver15#7-unable-to-install-python-packages-using-pip-after-installing-sql-server-2019-on-windows

Answer (score 2):

This issue occurs when we compile python from source without installing some packages that helps with ssl. Here is how to fix this in a Debian based Linux system.

```
sudo apt install build-essential pkg-config zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev libsqlite3-dev libbz2-dev
./configure --enable-optimizations
make -j 4 
sudo make altinstall
```

Note that -j 4 specifies that I want to use 4 CPU threads. You can check how many threads your CPU has by running `nproc`

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is same issue in Anaconda prompt (Anaconda3) on Windows 10. Here is workaround: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10576

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this without having to change anything related to TSL/SSL.

I was trying to see if the same thing was happening to `pip`, and saw that `pip` was broken. Did some digging and realized it's probably caused by Homebrew deleted `python@2` on February 1st, 2020.

Running `brew uninstall python@2` to delete python2 installed by Homebrew.

Destroyed the virtual env created using `python3` and created a new one. 
`pip3` installing works fine again.

Comment: For me, switching to an older version of `openssl` worked:

`brew switch openssl 1.0.2t`

I'm on Mac OS Catalina 10.15.3. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am on macOS and I had used brew but what Vaulstein mentioned in his answer didn't cover my case.

I run the following commands to make sure my current python was not installed by brew

```
brew list | grep python           
python
python@2

brew info python
python@3.8: stable 3.8.3 (bottled)
Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
https://www.python.org/
Not installed
...
```

So I download the latest 3.8.5 from https://www.python.org/ and when installing it I saw following information

> **Certificate verification and OpenSSL**
>
> This package includes its own private copy of OpenSSL 1.1.1.  The
> trust certificates in system and user keychains managed by the
> *Keychain Access* application and the *security* command line utility are not used as defaults by the Python ssl module

After installed 3.8.5 it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got into this problem using Ubuntu, pyenv and Python 3.8.1 managed by pyenv. There was actually no way to get pip to work correctly, since every time I tried to install anything, including pip itself, the same error showed up.
Final solution was to install, via pyenv, a newer version, in this case 3.8.6. Apparently, from 3.8.4 Python is prepared to run SSL/TLS out of the box, so everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I simply solved the problem with following command:

**brew upgrade python@3.9**

SSL is included by default on this version!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was running into issues with my `$PATH` on Linux.  This can also happen on MacOS.

Check to see if `/usr/bin/pip3 install package_name_goes_here` works for you.  If so then run
`which pip3` this will tell you which is the first directory that pip3 is installed in.

If it is something like `/usr/local/bin/pip3` which is different from `/usr/bin/pip3` then you may need to adjust your $PATH.

Run
`echo $PATH` and copy the result.

The PATH is simply a colon separated list of directories that contain directories.  Bash will always return the first instance of the program that you are attempting to execute.  Move all the system directories upfront.  Here is a list of some of the system directories:

```
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
```

If that fails then verify you have `openssl` installed  by running `openssl version -a` if not then install openssl.

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed [anaconda](https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop-extras/blob/master/bucket/anaconda3.json) via [`scoop`](https://scoop.sh/), and encounter this error while using `pip` from within a `conda` environment you can resolve it by...

1. Adding these to your path

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\scoop\apps\anaconda3\current
C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\scoop\apps\anaconda3\current\Scripts
C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\scoop\apps\anaconda3\current\Library
C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\scoop\apps\anaconda3\current\Library\bin
```

2. Installing `openssl` via [`scoop`](https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Main/blob/master/bucket/openssl.json)

```
scoop install openssl
```

3. And copying the following DLLs from `..\anaconda3\Library\bin` to `..\anaconda3\DLLs`

References:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/54897379
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/60405693

Answer (score 1):

I exited my virtual environment and upgraded pip.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem! I accidentally installed the 32-bit version of Miniconda3. Make sure you choose the 64 bit version!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
yum install python36-pyOpenSSL
```

python version and package manager might differ.

Answer (score 0):

You’d try from Anaconda Prompt.

You will see (base), now upgrade pip.
Example:

```
(base) C:\Users\Tom>cd ..

(base) C:\Users>cd ..

(base) C:\>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in g:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (20.0.2)

(base) C:\>pip -V
pip 20.0.2 from G:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

# Try install
(base) C:\>pip install selenium
```

This takes a longer time, but will also install or upgrade SSL libraries that Anaconda uses internally. [Keep Going here](https://therefor.life/how-to-solve-an-issue-pip-installing-selenium-warning-tls-ssl/)

Comment: This answer assumes using conda on Windows, not vanilla python on Linux as the OP indicated

Answer (score 0):

You could try `brew link` and it will show you the proper instruction:

```
$ brew link openssl --force
Warning: Refusing to link macOS provided/shadowed software: openssl@1.1
If you need to have openssl@1.1 first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"

For pkg-config to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was because I changed the folder of the environment.
I just removed the env and reinstalled everything.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error:

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pb-tool/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pb-tool/
ERROR: Operation cancelled by user
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

In Anaconda I did it with this command:

```
conda install anaconda-navigator
```

It was mentioned in this article : [pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL however the ssl module in Python is not available](https://exerror.com/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available/)

Answer (score 0):

Even after trying all the above steps, i was getting the same error. So while we work in a lab and have authorised access to Internet,the issue was with old versions on servers. So i created a virtual environment and placed all my imported modules there. Gave all the necessary permission to the file and the user. Then i gave the internet access to the server system. It worked fine.
Try checking for any access and permission issue you might have.
Hope it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

For Miniconda3 under Windows 10 with python=3.7.5 I tried all above suggestions; nothing worked. I had to downgrade to python=3.7.0 which solved the issue

```
conda install python=3.7.0
```

Obviously this is quite messy. The answers suggest that an upgrade to 3.8.5 might also work but this had too many side effects in my env.

Answer (score -1):

Install openssl first.

If you are facing this issue in conda environment, you can install openssl
using `conda install -c anaconda openssl`. It enables ssl for you!

Answer (score -1):

After trying to compile python myself and still lacking the ssl module, i finally tried to just install the missing module from apt like this:

`apt install python3-openssl`

Answer (score -2):

I tried:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

And After that, it works fine for me in Windows 10.

Comment: How is pip supposed to upgrade pip if pip doesnt work?!

Comment: The question says "pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL". I had the same problem and the answer I wrote is how I fixed it.

Answer (score -3):

This is the problem with your default ssl setting. You gotta download the [Python3](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-381/) and add the path to your system. If you use Pycharm, set the interpreter to your python3 path. Then you can normally use the pip3 without error.