# pip is not working error: "No module named 'msvcrt''

Tags: python, pip, msvcrt

I uninstalled python3.4 and installed python3.9.2. Now `pip` is not working. `python3 -m pip install` is showing following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 73, in <module>
    import msvcrt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'msvcrt'
```

Simple python codes are running. My OS is openSUSE Leap 42.3. I have another python2.7 installed. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: May be is your py3.4 installed this package bug py3.9 is not, so ```cd``` your py3.9's pip dir and install again, or use py3.4 to run your code.

Comment: msvcrt is a windows-only package (msvcrt stands for MicroSoft Visual C RunTime and is typically found as msvcrt.dll on windows systems).

Comment: @spectras I agree with you but do not understand why this error comes.

Comment: @Johnny py3.4 is no more there.

Comment: The odd thing is that it does not continue. The expected code flow goes like this: try to load windows-only modules, and then if that fails assume posix. That exception you see is supposed to be caught.

Comment: Can you find the ```C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll``` file? If not, you need to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was about setting the path

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib64/python3.9/lib-dynload/ /usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201459/python-3-7-install-not-working-on-opensuse-leap-42-3?rq=1) was helpful.