# pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL

Tags: python, pip, rhel

Using Python 3.7.1 on RHEL.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49296846/9604804) it hasn't worked. And neither has any other solutions I've found...

Comment: It is a pity that so many distribution only provide a half installed Python! You will have to dive into the documentation of your system to know how you can get the **standard library** ssl module on it. I have no RHEL, but according to https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/2/html/Messaging_Installation_and_Configuration_Guide/Enable_SSL_in_Python_Clients.html , you could try to get the `python-ssl` package from the Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) repository.

Answer (score 0):

configure pip location at ~/.bashrc

```
$vi ~/.bashrc
```

refer to my settings for python, you can use your pip:

```
#set python environment viriable 
export PYTHON_HOME=/home/monjuu-g/anaconda2
export PATH=$PYTHON_HOME/bin:$PATH
```