# Python “SSLError(”Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.“)': /simple/docutils/”

Tags: python, django, ssl, pip, homebrew

**PROBLEM**

- Whatever I try to install from terminal with pip I get this error message
- I may have installed and fully deleted **homebrew** (macOS 10.12) before but I am not sure how to solve this
- The Django 3.0 app runs perfectly well

**Installs I try to run** (all cases same error message)

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install django-storages
pip install ssl
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django-storages/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django-storages/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django-storages/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django-storages/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django-storages/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/django-storages/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/django-storages/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-storages (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django-storages
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

**Tried Solutions**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59280089/10270590
- [pip TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53742171/pip-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-problem)
- [pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in/59280089#59280089)
- @hoefling https://stackoverflow.com/users/2650249/hoefling recommended to run: `python -c "import _ssl"`

  - RESULT: `dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
    Referenced from: /Users/..../django_app_mainfolder/ven/bin/python
    Reason: image not found
    Abort trap: 6`
  - Recommended solution: [Broken references in Virtualenvs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233252/broken-references-in-virtualenvs)
  - I was looking at the main ANSWER here but I have no idea what is going on https://stackoverflow.com/a/25947333/10270590 = [This is the origin of the answer](https://web.archive.org/web/20150206132233/https://wirtel.be/posts/en/2014/07/29/fix_virtualenv_python_brew/)
  - Not worked - https://stackoverflow.com/a/23660033/10270590
  - Non usable - I am not using brew now - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51145074/10270590

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3)? Seems like a library issue. Other than that, try re-installing Python

Comment: I n't know why my comments were deleted, so I repeat it again: you get an error when importing the `_ssl` module, so either your virtual env (if you use one) or even your python installation is borked You can check that by trying to import `_ssl` outside the virtual env. Thus the question again - how did you install python? How did you create the virtual env?

Comment: Another thing - don't do `pip install ssl`, it is part of the standard library and installing the third-party `ssl` will bring nothing in best case, causing more errors in worst.

Comment: I had to delete my question because, I have updated my question with some sensitive info, sorry. @hoefling just post this and I accept your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29969862/10270590

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29969862/10270590

go to your virtualenv directory (but don't run workon):

```
cd ~/.virtualenv/name_of_broken_venv
```

Now delete these files:

```
rm -rf .Python bin/python* lib/python2.7/* include/python2.7
```

Then to rebuild your venv, run:

```
virtualenv .
pip install -r requirements.txt
```