# pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available error

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, openssl

Trying to install and run Python 3.7.2 in my CentOS 6 machine with the following recipe:

```
yum -y update
yum install gcc
yum groupinstall -y "development tools"
yum install -y zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel readline-devel tk-devel gdbm-devel db4-devel libpcap-devel xz-devel expat-devel libffi-devel
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/3.7.2/Python-3.7.2.tar.xz
tar -xf Python-3.7.2.tar.xz
cd Python-3.7.2
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"
make && make altinstall
```

Everything goes fine with the installation. But as soon as I try to first install any python package with pip ...

```
pip3.7 install requests
```

I get the error:

```
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting requests
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/requests/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/requests/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/requests/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/requests/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/requests/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/requests/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/requests/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

Doesn't make sense since I got the SSL module installed as you can see:

```
[root@xxx Python-3.7.2]# rpm -qa | grep openssl
openssl-1.0.1e-57.el6.x86_64
openssl-devel-1.0.1e-57.el6.x86_64
```

Already tried everything and searched tons, how to solve this issue?

Comment: Tried the exact yum line from here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49296846/9638646

Comment: yep, only says that I have already everything up to date @Craftables