# Could not fetch URL (python3.6 pip problem)

Tags: python, ssl, pip, python-3.6, discord.py

Im trying to install discord.py on python 3.6

I've tried

`python3.6 -m pip install discord.py`

But it gives me :

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: discord.py in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord.py-1.0.1-py3.6.egg (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp<3.6.0,>=3.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp-3.5.4-py3.6-linux-armv7l.egg (from discord.py) (3.5.4)
Collecting websockets<7.0,>=6.0 (from discord.py)

  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/websockets/

  #more retries

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/websockets/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/websockets/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)) - skipping

  Could not fetch URL https://www.piwheels.org/simple/websockets/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.piwheels.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/websockets/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement websockets<7.0,>=6.0 (from discord.py) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for websockets<7.0,>=6.0 (from discord.py)

pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)) - skipping
Could not fetch URL https://www.piwheels.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.piwheels.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)) - skipping
```

The line that most caught my attention was:

`pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.`

but i don't know what this means

Comment: Do you have openssl installed?

Answer (score 0):

The last answer in the below link might be of some use:

[pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in)

In addition, try running the pip installation through Anaconda prompt if anaconda is installed.