# How to install pyttsx in Anaconda3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, anaconda

How to install pyttsx in Anaconda3 (Python3.7) windows 10 machine? I tried to install but getting the error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyttsx3 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyttsx3

C:\Users\Ramesh\Anaconda3\Scripts>pip install pyttsx3
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting pyttsx3
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pyttsx3/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pyttsx3/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pyttsx3/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pyttsx3/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pyttsx3/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pyttsx3/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pyttsx3/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyttsx3 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyttsx3
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was facing the same problem.The steps I followed to solve it are:

1. Go to Anaconda prompt and type `conda install pip` . This will install pip in the current conda environment.

2.After step 1, type `pip install pyttsx3`  .

Some additional links for help,see under Installing non-conda packages-[Managing Conda packages](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your error message:

```
however the ssl module in Python is not available
```

Try this:

```
pip install ssl
```

Comment: Thanks for your time.
I tired your command "pip install ssl", i am getting this error

  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ssl (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ssl

Answer (score 0):

If you install it with pip in the same environment as conda, the latest changes from pip overwrite conda settings and vice versa. You must create a separate env for pip packages.