# gdal with openssl 1.1 breaks pip install and other stuff that depends on openssl 1.0 on macos

Tags: pip, openssl, gdal

I need to install gdal.
So i run:

> brew install gdal

Current version is: 2.4.4_4

and has a dependency on openssl 1.1

After successfully installed, if I go into my virtualenv, I see the following:

> WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL,
>   however the ssl module in Python is not available.

That is because pip (and other software) dependes on older version of openssl (version 1.0.x).

After searching I found this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59280089/237115

where I found a way to fix the issue, by installing older version of openssl.
But of course now gdal doesnt work without openssl1.1

any way to fix this ?