# TLS/SSL error while installing Openpyxl package in Pycharm on WIndows 10

Tags: python, ssl, pip, pycharm, openpyxl

Tried installing openpyxl from pypi.org in Pycharm's terminal by copy-pasting this code "pip install openpyxl'

Got this error

pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL. however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting openpyxl
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/openpyxl/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/openpyxl/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/openpyxl/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/openpyxl/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/openpyxl/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/openpyxl/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/openpyxl/ (Caused by SSLError
("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openpyxl (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for openpyxl
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't conn
ect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

I updated Pycharm.
installed OpenSSL.

Tried changing the URL in settings > python interpreter > + sign > manage respirators, but couldn't find the 'manage respirators' option.

What should I do? TIA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in)

Comment: If anyone is curious, this is the video which has helped me fix this error

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvbUqf3Tb1s&t=513s&ab_channel=TechWithTim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across a similar problem and the following trick worked.

Activate your base conda environment first. After that activate your project's python environment. Then go ahead and install openpyxl using pip install command.