# Can't install any package via `pip` on windows 10, ssl module in Python is not available

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, pip, pycharm

`WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.`

`There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnection`

`(Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))`

This is the error I get when I try to `pip install` anything. `pip install` used to work for me, but I recently tried it again and it hasn't been working. I've seen this same question asked before, and they usually say,

> add the following in environment paths:
>
> ```
> D:\Anaconda3; 
> D:\Anaconda3\Scripts; 
> D:\Anaconda3\Library\bin
> ```

However, I don't use Anaconda. I simply have Python 3.8 installed, and I normally use my PyCharm installation to install packages. I have also tried installing OpenSSL from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html, since that was mentioned as a solution.

None of this is working, and I am getting the same errors. If someone could help, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should post the errors

Comment: Is something wrong with PyCharm? Every time you create a new project you have the option of setting up a virtual environment and then you should be free to install whatever through the PyCharm terminal

Comment: @jordanm I edited the question to add the errors.

Comment: @notacorn I don't think I've ever created a virtual environment with PyCharm. Normally when I use PyCharm to install a package, it's just because the import is underlined in red, so I click it, and it shows me a button where I can install that package.

 If I want to choose a specific package to install, I usually just go to their package search menu and find it there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in)