# Python launcher tries to run Pip from a Python installation that I've already uninstalled

Tags: python, windows, pip

I am having trouble installing a few modules on my Windows computer (namely TensorFlow). I used to have Python 3.5 and 3.7 installed on this computer, but have since uninstalled Python 3.5 through the Control Panel. However, when I try to check the version of PIP, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\yoonh\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe"  "C:\Users\yoonh\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\Scripts\pip.exe" --version'
```

Meanwhile, following other instructions and using `py -m pip ...` gives me the following error:
`WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.`

I would really appreciate if someone could help me solve this issue! Thank you!

Comment: Please show the output of `echo %PATH%` and `py --list-paths` and also check if you have any envvars that affect Python, e.g. `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Checking envvars can be done with `set | find "PYTHON"`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in

Comment: The relevant output of PATH is ```C:\Users\yoonh\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\Scripts;C:\Users\yoonh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Scripts;;```.

Comment: list-paths outputs:
```-3.7-64        C:\Users\yoonh\Anaconda3\python.exe *```
```-3.7-32        C:\Users\yoonh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe```

Comment: Please edit this into your question instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information you provided, it looks like you still have Python 3.5 installed for your account locally, or some leftovers from it.

---

- First, if you just uninstalled Python 3.5, make sure that you closed and restarted your command prompt from the Start Menu after uninstalling Python. To be extra sure, restart your system just to ensure that the uninstallation is fully complete (it may not be if e.g. some files from it were in use while you were uninstalling. Windows Installer tells you if this happens and that you need to restart but many users have a bad habit of not reading warnings.).
- Run `appwiz.cpl` as yourself (without elevation) and uninstall Python 3.5 if present
- Delete `c:\users\yoonh\appdata\local\programs\python\python35` and anything under it; delete it from `PATH`, too, if present (run `SystemPropertiesAdvanced` -> "Environment variables")
- Check the registry at `HKCU\Software\Python\PythonCore` and `HKCU\Software\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore` and same under `HKLM` for any subkeys pointing to installations that don't actually exist