# Failing to load package using reticulate::use_virtualenv

Tags: r, virtualenv, reticulate

I have been trying to run some python code via R reticulate with no success. I tried creating a virtual environment and install two packages in it: numpy and a GitHub package called scrublet.

```
library(reticulate)
if(!"r-scrublet" %in% virtualenv_list()) {
  virtualenv_create("r-scrublet")
  virtualenv_install("r-scrublet", c("numpy","git+https://github.com/AllonKleinLab/scrublet.git"))
}
use_virtualenv(virtualenv = "r-scrublet", required = T)
```

Then I want to activate the environment and run code over it. When I run `py_discover_config()` I get output:

```
python:         C:/Users/gilad/Documents/.virtualenvs/r-scrublet/Scripts/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/gilad/Documents/.virtualenvs/r-scrublet/Scripts/python36.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/gilad/Documents/.virtualenvs/r-scrublet
version:        3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:/Users/gilad/Documents/.virtualenvs/r-scrublet/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.19.1

NOTE: Python version was forced by use_python function
```

which seems to be as I want. The problem is that I don't seem to be able to actually use this environment. If I test weather numpy is available (`py_numpy_available()`) I get that not and when I try any `import` statement (either to one of the installed packages or even to something like `os`) R crashes with:

> R Session Aborted. R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated

I tried the different reticulate manuals ([here](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/versions.html) and [here](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/python_packages.html)) and different git issues or SO questions but couldn't still figure this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the installation path you provide, it looks like you're using Windows.
If you refer to [virtualenv doc](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/reference/virtualenv-tools.html) :

> Virtual environment functions are not supported on Windows (the use of [conda environments](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/reference/conda-tools.html) is recommended on Windows).

Try:

```
library(reticulate)
conda_create("r-scrublet")
conda_install(envname="r-scrublet", packages ="numpy","pip","git")

conda_python(envname =  "r-scrublet")
```

The scrublet.git can be added by running from the `r-scrublet` environment root folder:

```
Scripts\pip install git+https://github.com/AllonKleinLab/scrublet.git
```

or directly from R:

```
conda_install(envname='r-scrublet','git+https://github.com/AllonKleinLab/scrublet.git',pip=T)
```

provided that you apply this [patch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62264725/13513328). To avoid the patch, you can probably to add `\r-scrublets\Library\bin` to system path.

---

For completeness of snippet, once setup is ready, specify it's use by:

```
use_miniconda("r-scrublet", required=T)
scrub <- import("scrublet")
```

Comment: @Gilad, see my edit to avoid installation from terminal.

Comment: Thanks very much :) Was confusing myself with working on both unix and windows and loosing track of what was working and not in each. But now works nicely :)