# Pip can't detect latest python version

Tags: python, pip

I just installed Python 3.8.0 on my raspberry pi OS, I have already configure it, such that Python 3.8.0 is the default version, however whenever I pip install anything it can't detect python 3.8, it's still stuck with my previous python version. When I type in pip3.8 install, this `WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.` happen

Comment: this error seems to happen if openssl is not correctly configured see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in

Comment: `Could not build the ssl module!
Python requires an OpenSSL 1.0.2 or 1.1 compatible libssl with X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host().
LibreSSL 2.6.4 and earlier do not provide the necessary APIs, https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable/issues/381
`
this appear when I `make` in the python3.8 directory

Comment: you need `libssl-dev` installed while building -- also I'd suggest 3.8.5 if you're building from source, 3.8.0 is a little old by now