# how do I install openCV on pycharm

Tags: windows, opencv, pip, pycharm

I have version 3.8 of python and I need to install opencv package on pycharm so I tried this command `pip3 install opencv-python` (on terminal of pycharm).

I got **WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.**

Is there any solution to fix that prob ?

Thanks!

Comment: I hope this link helps you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in

Answer (score 0):

installing packages/libs on Pychram are very easy you just need to import the lib that you want and it will show you an install option and if it dose not show you it you can press on file on the upper left , go to setting then go to python interpreter there will be a plus sign and you can just search for the packages/libs and download it

Comment: example ```import cv2``` or ```import cv```and it will show you the packge to install.

Comment: this a tip for the future so you wont need to pip install every time you want to import a package.

Comment: thanks for the aswer . I did it but it doesnt work !

Comment: To install the package opencv  use one of the 2 examples that I commented (I would use first example).