# sherlock requirements installation problem

Tags: python

I am using kali linux

```
kali@kali:~$ uname -a
Linux kali 5.9.0-kali2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.9.6-1kali1 (2020-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I was trying to install sherlock from Github [https://github.com/sherlock-project/sherlock].

1.clone the repo:

```
kali@kali:~/Downloads$ git clone https://github.com/sherlock-project/sherlock.git
```

2.cd to sherlock:

```
kali@kali:~/Downloads$ cd sherlock/
```

3.ls:

```
kali@kali:~/Downloads/sherlock$ ls
CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md  Dockerfile  README.md           requirements.txt  sites.md
CONTRIBUTING.md     images      removed_sites.json  sherlock
docker-compose.yml  LICENSE     removed_sites.md    site_list.py
```

4.install requirements:

```
kali@kali:~/Downloads/sherlock$ python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/beautifulsoup4/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3..
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2...
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1...
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0...                                                            
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/beautifulsoup4/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/beautifulsoup4/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement beautifulsoup4>=4.8.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: none)                                                
ERROR: No matching distribution found for beautifulsoup4>=4.8.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))                                                                                           
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.                                                                            
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

I tried to install requirements with sudo user, it was still not working.

I tried all the answers provides here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in/62264725#62264725] but none of them worked.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Install beautifulsoup manually.  [install tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/beautiful_soup/beautiful_soup_installation.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try using stem from PyPi instead of Git version. It should fix the issue installing the stem module.

Comment: Tried ```pip install sherlock```and failed.