# ```WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available```

Tags: python, ssl, terminal

Whenever I try to **execute** this command in the **PyCharm** terminal `pip install django==3.1.4`, the terminal window comes up with an error saying `WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in)

Comment: No!! That doesn't works

Comment: There are about 32 answers to that question... 
What is your OS and python, pip versions? Can you try running "pip3 install ..." rather than "pip install ..."?