# Installing packages in virtual environment on Windows

Tags: python, package, virtual-environment

I started building a virtual environment based on this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QkOKkrKqI-k) to deploy a dash application. However, I cannot install packages and always get the same error:

**WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.**

```
C:\Path\mkdir "Project 1"
C:\Path\Project 1>py -m venv env
C:\Path\Project 1>.\env\Scripts\activate

(env) C:\Path\Project 1\env\Scripts>pip install numpy
(env) C:\Path\Project 1\env\pip install numpy
```

I did go through the guide (https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/) how to set up a virtual environment but it did work either.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem had been explained and solved.
[pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in)