# Installed Python 3.10 on Ubuntu: pip not working

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I have installed Python 3.10 as python3 from source [using these commands](https://github.com/python/cpython#id4), If I create a virtual environment using:

```
python3 -m venv env
```

It successfully creates the virtual environment but installing using PIP gives an error. Previously the error was SSL but I re-installed SSL dependencies again [using this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in) and Python. It stopped giving SSL errors but still, it wasn't able to install a package using pip. It gave the error no matched package.
It also says the pip is not the latest. If I try to update it the process follows but only the old version is installed not the new.
Currently there are two python versions installed on my OS.

```
>> which python
/usr/bin/python
>> which pip
/home/user/.local/bin/pip
>> which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
>> which pip3
/home/user/.local/bin/pip3
```

If I follow all the stuff using python (which is 3.8.10), everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with TensorFlow. I was trying to install TensorFlow with Python 3.10. TensorFlow currently doesn't support Python 3.10 therefore, it was showing the error of `not matching any distribution`. For other packages, it just worked fine. It currently [supports only up to Python 3.9](https://www.tensorflow.org/install).