# Problems with installing modules in Python / Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

I want to import some modules in my virtual environment like Flask, Pandas, Matplotlib etc.
But the problem is that the terminal returns me the following issue:

```
(env) PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\Mehr\Python\Blockchain-Course> pip install matplotlib
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/matplotlib/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/matplotlib/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/matplotlib/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/matplotlib/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/matplotlib/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/matplotlib/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/matplotlib/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for matplotlib
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.3; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Mehr\Python\Blockchain-Course\env\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I've never had any problems with it and yesterday it worked perfectly, does someone knows what to do?

Comment: This might help - [pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in)

Comment: Does this answer your question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. first install openssl, please refer to [this page](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001435926-Installing-OpenSSL-locally-under-your-username)
2. install python and ./configure --with-openssl=/home/username/openssl
   at last
3. run python -m ssl and nothing outputs, it's ok.

You can refer to [this page](https://github.com/actions/setup-python/issues/93#issuecomment-716433622) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could have been caused by the `DLLs` in the `C:\Windows\System32` folder (e.g. libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll or libssl-1_1-x64.dll or others) placed there by other software.

It may be fixed installing `openSSL` from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html which replaces the dlls by more recent versions.

Comment: Well is there any other way instead of downloading this program? I do not feel safe with it