# How to fix "pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available" when installing Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was trying to install TensorFlow with Anaconda 3.9.9.

I ran the command

```
pip install tensorflow
```

and there was an error saying:

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/tensorflow/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/tensorflow/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate:  HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/tensorflow/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I have tried adding `/anaconda3`, `/anaconda3/Scripts` and `/anaconda3/library/bin` to the Path variable. I have also tried running the command:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org tensorflow
```

but nothing seems to be working.

Did I miss anything and are there any other solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running below command to fix this issue:

```
pip install --upgrade
pip install ssl
```

Please create an virtual_environment to install `TensorFlow` in `Anaconda`.

Follow below code to install `TensorFlow` in virtual_environment:

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow  #Create a Virtual environment(tf).
conda activate tf              #Activate the Virtual environment
pip install tensorflow         #install TensorFlow in it.
```

**Note:** You need to activate the virtual_environment each time you want to use TensorFlow.