# "How to fix pip install error in pycharm?"

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

When trying to install Django in the PyCharm terminal, I get an error:

*pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.*

Changes to path and openSSL didn't help, what other ways are there?

windows 10, in addition to PyCharm installed Anaconda

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in) answer your question?

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: @ndrew are you sure [one of these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22pip%20is%20configured%20with%20locations%20that%20require%20TLS%2fSSL%22&searchOn=3) doesn't solve the problem?