# Debian 11 : pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available

Tags: python, ssl, installation, pip, pyenv

I've installed Python 3.11 in Debian 11 but after installing when I want to use `pip3.11` with any package it throws the warning: `pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the SSL module in Python is not available` and fails to download.

I've done

```
cd Python 3.11.5
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-optimizations --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"
sudo make
sudo make altinstall
```

Also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in), [this](https://sudo%20apt%20install%20openssl), and other similar solutions.

When I run `sudo make` it prompts

```
*** WARNING: renaming "_crypt" since importing it failed: libcrypt.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_hashlib              _ssl                  _tkinter           
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.


The following modules built successfully but were removed because they could not be imported:
_crypt                                                         


Could not build the SSL module!
Python requires an OpenSSL 1.1.1 or newer
```

But I have it installed.

Tried: `/configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-optimizations --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib" --with-openssl="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/openssl"` but did not work either.

What can I do to build those missing packages? The one I'm most interested in is in SSL handler because it doesn't let me do anything with pip.

EDIT:

Tried installing wiht `pyenv`, same result:

```
File "/home/juanc/.pyenv/versions/3.10.12/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 99, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'
ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?

Please consult to the Wiki page to fix the problem.
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems
```

I've reinstalled `openssl` following [this](https://orcacore.com/install-openssl-3-debian-11/) tutorial (before I had it installed with `brew`) and now the path is `/usr/local/bin/openssl`.

Followed the pyenv [wiki](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems):

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include" \
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib64" \
pyenv install -v 3.10 # 3.11 is not available
```

But `openssl` keeps missing when python is built.

Pyenv ends with "succes", but there is nothing in `~/.pyenv/versions/` and `pyenv versions` does not recognize any other python version than system's.

Any clue?

Comment: Before running `./configure` you need to install a lot of dependencies. For `_ssl` you need to install `libssl-dev`: `sudo apt install -y libssl-dev`

Comment: My advice is to use [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#readme). See also https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment for the list of required dependencies.

Comment: Another advice: use `conda`. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bconda%5D+install+python and https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python

Comment: @phd thank's for your help. I do not like conda, I would prefer not no install it. I've already have `libssl-dev` installed. Followed your pyenv advice, but's the same, ssl keeps appearing. I'll update the question.